# Hugging face: RuntimeError: model_init should have 0 or 1 argument

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I’m trying to tune hyper-params with the following code:

```
def my_hp_space(trial):
    return {
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 5e-3, 5e-5),
        "arr_gradient_accumulation_steps": trial.suggest_int("num_train_epochs", 8, 16),
        "arr_per_device_train_batch_size": trial.suggest_int(2, 4),        
    }


def get_model(model_name, config):
    return AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)

def compute_metric(eval_predictions):
    
    metric         = load_metric('accuracy')    
    logits, labels = eval_predictions
    predictions    = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

training_args   = TrainingArguments(output_dir='test-trainer', 
                                    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                    num_train_epochs= 10)
data_collator   = default_data_collator
model_name      = 'sentence-transformers/nli-roberta-base-v2'
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name,num_labels=3)

trainer = Trainer(
    model_init      = get_model(model_name, config),
    args            = training_args,
    train_dataset   = tokenized_datasets['TRAIN'],
    eval_dataset    = tokenized_datasets['TEST'],    
    compute_metrics = compute_metric,
    tokenizer       = None,
    data_collator   = data_collator,
)

best = trainer.hyperparameter_search(direction="maximize", hp_space=my_hp_space)
```

And getting error:

```
 1173     model = self.model_init(trial)
   1174 else:
-> 1175     raise RuntimeError("model_init should have 0 or 1 argument.")
   1177 if model is None:
   1178     raise RuntimeError("model_init should not return None.")

RuntimeError: model_init should have 0 or 1 argument.
```

1. What am I doing wrong ?
2. How can I fix it and run hyper parameter method and get best model parameters ?

Comment: Can you please post the full error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.model_init) you have to pass the `model_init` as a callable.

```py
trainer = Trainer(
    model_init      = get_model,
    args            = training_args,
    train_dataset   = tokenized_datasets['TRAIN'],
    eval_dataset    = tokenized_datasets['TEST'],    
    compute_metrics = compute_metric,
    tokenizer       = None,
    data_collator   = data_collator,
)
```

Additionally there seems to be an issue with with the number of defined parameters in your passed `model_init` function. Your function `get_model` requires two parameters, while only 0 or 1 may be passed. The huggingface documentation states

> The function may have zero argument, or a single one containing the optuna/Ray Tune/SigOpt trial object, to be able to choose different architectures according to hyper parameters (such as layer count, sizes of inner layers, dropout probabilities etc).

You can define your parameters inside the `get_model` function and it works.

```py
def get_model():
    model_name = 'sentence-transformers/nli-roberta-base-v2'
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name,num_labels=3)
    return AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)
```

The [official raytune example](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8beb887bbed31ecea3d2813b61833b81c45712e1/python/ray/tune/examples/pbt_transformers/pbt_transformers.py#L27) contains some code how to keep your parametrisation. They define an additional function `tune_transformer`and define `get_model` inside the function scope of `tune_transformer`. You can check their example, if you want to keep your parametrisation

Hope it helps.